# Getting error: bad register name `%bpl'

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86

I'm trying to install a library, fec-3.0.1, needed for my project. After configuring it, I'm getting this error:

```
gcc  -g  -02  -I.  -Wall  -march=i686     -c -o viterbi27_port.o viterbi27_port.c
fec.h: Assembler messages:
fec.h267: Error: bad register name '%bpl'
make: *** [viterbi27_port.o] Error 1
```

Actually, I've encountered such errors several times before, during installation of some other libraries. I'm using Ubuntu Linux on VMware Player as a virtual machine. What should I do?

Comment: This sounds like broken inline assembly, or misdetected architecture. `bpl` is only accessible in 64 bit mode.

Answer (score 2):

The inline asm in `fec.h` uses wrong constraints. One possible fix is:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("test %1,%1;setpo %0" : "=qhm" (x) : "qh" (x));
```